# sorting relationships in a graph database by reverse chronological order

Tags: sorting, graph, nosql, reverse, graph-databases

suppose I'm making a social application whose data I store with a graph db, where entities (people, things...) are nodes (w/ property "name") and actions are relationships (w/ properties "what" and "when").
also suppose huge db and high load so the implementation should not just work, it should be as fast as possible.

how would you answer questions like "what happened in the last 5 minutes?" that list actions (and their subjects/objects) in reverse chronological order?

Comment: I know nothing about graph databases but it seems you'd have to convert your actions into first-class nodes in order to define indexing over them... or maybe make a "last5minutesList" (ordered by date/time) and depurate it each time you add a new item: `1) add item at the end 2) traverse list from the beginning removing each older-than-5m item` :)

Comment: wrt your first, still I'd have to read the whole graph to sort these "action nodes" out. the last5MinutesList can work, but it can be a synchronization bottleneck (as potentially millions of new actions will cause its update)

Comment: But it's controlled. If it's an in-memory list (I don't think so) each new item has O(1) insertion (at the end) and O(1) deletion (will be checked and deleted only once). I mean: N inserted items will provoke: N insertions at the end plus N deletion try outs. Each deletion tryout has a last and failed check (the first node that you can't delete) and some deletes. Reorganizing this each item provokes: 1 insertion, 1 failed check, its own deletion. -> O(1).

Comment: If you maintain the last5minutesList in the BD I think the access time will be influentiated by the indexing mechanism. It's an ordered index so I think access time will be O(logN). Insertion at the end: O(logN). Find first to try deletion: O(logN). Deletion of each item: O(logN). So, each item processing time will be O(logN) (but with N being the count for the last 5 minutes events).